# How do you prove that this semiring's set function is not σ-additive?

Tags: measure-theory

My question concerns [Exercise 1.2.1 from "Probability Theory, a Comprehensive Course" (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bAPk.png) by Achim Klenke.

I have completed the question except for showing that *µ* is not *σ*-additive.

I have tried to create a counterexample by first creating an countably infinite series. Each member of the series is **another** countably infinite series of members of . All these members of  across all these series are pairwise disjoint but still have their collective union in .

Then I merged all the members into a single series but where they appear in a different order. Hoping that the sum of *µ* applied to each member would now converge to another value, I was disappointed (it still converged to the value of *µ* applied to the collective union).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily extend $\mu$ to the field $F$ generated by $\mathcal A$, which is just the collection of finite unions of elements of $\mathcal A$ plus $\mathbb Q$ itself since $\mathcal A$ is a semiring. If $\mu$ were countable additive then it would also extend to a measure on the $\sigma$-field generated by $F$, which includes singletons and hence is simply the power set of $\mathbb Q$. We would then have $\mu(\{x\})=0$ and hence $\mu(B)=0$ for all sets $B$, leading to a contradiction.

(For future posts, it's best to write out your question in full rather than linking to it.)

EDIT: Since you have not yet seen the Caratheodory Extension Theorem, a more direct approach is needed. Let $B=(0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$. We know $B$ is countable so let $\{x_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be an enumeration with $x_1<\frac16$. For each $n$ define $B_n=(x_n-3^{-n},x_n]\cap\mathbb Q$. Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n=(x_1-\frac13,1]\cap\mathbb Q\in\mathcal A$, and so by monotonicity
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(B_n)=\frac12<1=\mu(B)\le\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right).$$
In particular, $\mu$ is not countably subadditive and so it cannot be countably additive.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but I'm not accepting it (even though I'm convinced it's correct) because by the aforementioned exercise, the book has yet not covered your method for proving non _σ_-additivity. In fact, it does it a bit afterwards. So there should be an "easier" way of doing it. If you don't have the book at hand, then can you atleast provide a counterexample for a specific infinite series of disjoint members of the class that have their collective union in the class but that still don't fullfill _σ_-additivity for _µ_?

Comment: I will edit in more.

Comment: Hello again. Thank you for your proof. I'm just curious why are you invoking monotonicity to show the final inequality concerning B and the union of all B[n]s? The B[n]s aren't mutually disjoint so that final inequality does **not** show that _µ_ isn't _σ_-additive. So what role does that inequality play? But I do understand that the inequality before that shows that _µ_ isn't _σ_-subadditive and since we have a semiring and _µ_ is a content then it can't be _σ_-additive. Again, thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your question? Countable subadditivity means $\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right)\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(B_n)$ - everything I do is to show this fails.

Comment: Ok I see, so by **that** you wanted to show it's not countably subadditive. But you had already showed it before that since B is also a subset of the union of the B[n]s but the inequality with regard to _µ_ isn't fullfilled. So I was only confused why you proceeded with another inequality. Again, thanks (I'm a new user so I can't upvote).

Comment: The standard definition of countable subadditivity is what I have written. Some authors use $B\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n\Rightarrow\mu(B)\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(B_n)$, but I find this definition a little pointless. The standard definition is a more obvious analogue to $f(x+y)\le f(x)+f(y)$ which defines a subadditive function on $\mathbb R$, and if $\mu$ is monotone (as is the case if $\mu$ is finitely additive, or a "content" as you have called it) they are equivalent.